# Enumerate Databases Using SQL PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sqlps

I'm using PowerShell 4.0 and the SQLPS plugin for working with SQL Server.

```
ForEach($Database in (Get-ChildItem -FORCE SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases))
{
    Write-Host $Database
}
```

This outputs a list of database I have locally such as:

> [Test_1]
>   [DBA]
>   [Test_2]

However if I try to do something with the $Database like

```
ForEach($Database in (Get-ChildItem -FORCE SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases))
{
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $Database -HostName WIN-MAINV98PDFA -Query "select db_name()" -ServerInstance LocalHost
}
```

I get an error:

> WARNING: Using provider context. Server = localhost. Invoke-Sqlcmd :
>   Cannot open database "[Test_1]" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'WIN-MAINV98PDFA\admin'. At line:3
>   char:5
>   +     Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $Database -HostName WIN-MAINV98PDFA -Query "select d ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

I think problem boils down to the difference between--the brackets.

Works:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database Test_1 -HostName WIN-MAINV98PDFA -Query "select db_name()" -ServerInstance LocalHost
```

and

Fails:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database [Test_1] -HostName WIN-MAINV98PDFA -Query "select db_name()" -ServerInstance LocalHost
```

This seems like something  that should just work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object stored in the `$Database` variable is probably a complex type, and contains more information than just the database's name. Run this command, to see if there is a property that contains the database name without the square brackets around it:

```
$Database | Select-Object -Property *;
```

Assuming that there is something like a `Name` property, then pass in just the database's name by referencing that property.

```
ForEach($Database in (Get-ChildItem -FORCE SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases))
{
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $Database.Name -HostName WIN-MAINV98PDFA -Query "select db_name()" -ServerInstance LocalHost
}
```

Here is an example, using a Windows Service instead of a `Database` object.

[image: Screenshot]